# Trying to print List into .txt only getting first line of contents

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am very new to C# so please dont judge me a lot :/
So i want the contents of the lists (Jazz,metal,pop,folk) to be added in a .txt file. when i do run the program it runs successfully and generates the file. But the file only has the word jazz in it. Of course i want all 4 lists to be working but i am trying only with jazz for now.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Vocalist> jazz = new List<Vocalist>();
        List<Vocalist> metal = new List<Vocalist>();
        List<Vocalist> pop = new List<Vocalist>();
        List<Vocalist> folk = new List<Vocalist>();
        
       
                string recGenre;
                Console.WriteLine("Which type of genre records you want to extract");
                recGenre = Console.ReadLine();
                if (recGenre == "jazz")
                foreach (Vocalist i in jazz) 
                {   
                    //FileStream Vocal = new FileStream("C:/Users/NikolaosParadeisanos/Desktop/jazz.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                    File.WriteAllText("C:/Users/NikolaosParadeisanos/Desktop/jazz.txt", Convert.ToString(i.name));
                    File.WriteAllText("C:/Users/NikolaosParadeisanos/Desktop/jazz.txt", Convert.ToString(i.origin));
                    File.WriteAllText("C:/Users/NikolaosParadeisanos/Desktop/jazz.txt", Convert.ToString(i.vocalistType));
                    File.WriteAllText("C:/Users/NikolaosParadeisanos/Desktop/jazz.txt", Convert.ToString(i.genre));
                }
                
                    //
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed in the method description *if the target file already exists, it is overwritten*. That means that every time you  write in the specified file it gets overwritten with the last content (as you add the genre last it is the only thing left in the file. Try `File.AppendAllLines` instead.

```
File.AppendAllLines(@"C:/Users/NikolaosParadeisanos/Desktop/jazz.txt", new[] { Convert.ToString(i.name), Convert.ToString(i.origin), Convert.ToString(i.vocalistType), Convert.ToString(i.genre) });
```

Comment: So how do i fix it.

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot for your help brother. Cheers!

Comment: @MapleSapling try the above example it should work just fine. Also are you sure about using `Convert.ToString` instead of `.ToString()` ? Do you expect any `null` values ?

Comment: @dimitar.d Check this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers :)